# PHP/MySQL INNER JOIN Triples the amount of rows?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a system where I getting images out of my database, but when it does that, there is 3x of the same images.

I have tried with different ways, DISTINCT and such, but I have no clue how I fix this.

Here is my query code:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM billeder INNER JOIN album ON fk_album_ID = $id";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $thumb_src = 'billeder/thumb_'.$row['billeder_sti'];
    $full_src = 'billeder/'.$row['billeder_sti'];

    echo "
            <div class='ikon'>
                <a href='$full_src'>
                    <img src='$thumb_src' alt='' />
                </a>
            </div>
    ";
}

?>
```

Hope someone can help me on the way to fix this :)

Comment: Do you have any foreign key to join these 2 tables?

Comment: How should I create that? I know where I create it, but not sure how to :)

Comment: Post your tables, so we can help you. Your `JOIN` is not joining two table columns, that's why it's not working properly.

Comment: Post table structure and tell how they link with each other.

Comment: If you can setup an example on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) this will greatly help with the support you receive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JOIN` must be used with two tables columns. See example:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA a INNER JOIN tableB b ON a.id = b.a_id;
```

What you're trying to make is something like this:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT * FROM billeder INNER JOIN album ON 
    billeder.fk_album_ID = album.album_id WHERE billeder.id = $id"
```

You shouldn't pass an argument to the `JOIN`. The arguments must be used on the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks man I got it working! :)                                            $query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM billeder INNER JOIN album ON fk_album_ID = album_ID WHERE album_ID = $id";

Comment: @kristian You may accept the answer if the question is solved.

Comment: I need 15 reputation to do that ;/

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to see your table structure I won't be able to give an exact answer but the likely reason is because your `INNER JOIN` is not setup correctly.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM billeder
INNER JOIN album
    ON (billeder.fk_album_ID = album.pk_album_ID)
WHERE
    billeder.fk_album_ID = $id
```

Something like the above would be the correct way to `JOIN` a table and using a `WHERE` clause to then limit the date received.